# Adding new data to class in a Django model

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form which requires adding a standard name and if there is an option to add additional names to be added I want to create another input for it. I am not sure how to do that in regard to the Models, and migrating and creating the html related to the new name to take in the input.

I have created the form with the following models:

```
    ownerName1= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Owner Name 1')
    ownerRole1= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Owner Role 1')
    ownershipPercentage1= models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Business Phone 1')
```

I added in the HTML template a button to add a new shareholder if available so I want if the button is clicked to create the following in the models.py

```
    ownerName2= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Owner Name 2')
    ownerRole2= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Owner Role 2')
    ownershipPercentage2= models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Business Phone 2')
```

and if pressed one more time the number changes to 3 and so on.

Subsequently in needs to be updates in the form:

```
class infoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = ['ownerName1','ownerRole1','ownershipPercentage1']
```

Here is an example of the form:

```
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ownershipStructure" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-3-tab">
                    <h2>Ownership Structure</h2>
                    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                      <input type="text" name="ownerName1" id="ownerName1" class="form-control"
                        {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.ownerName1.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                      <label class="form-label">Name of Owner(s)/Major Shareholders:</label>
                      {% for err in form.ownerName1.errors %}
                          <small class="text-danger ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="row mb-4">
                        <div class="col">
                          <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input
                              type="text"
                              id="ownerRole1" name="ownerRole1" class="form-control" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.ownerRole1.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                            <label class="form-label">Role:</label>
                            {% for err in form.ownerRole1.errors %}
                                <small class="text-danger ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Number input -->
                        <div class="col">
                          <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input
                              type="number" id="ownershipPercentage1" class="form-control" name="ownershipPercentage1" {% if form.is_bound %}value="{{ form.ownershipPercentage1.value }}"{% endif %}/>
                            <label class="form-label" for="ownershipPercentage1" style="margin-left: 0px"
                              >Ownership Percentage</label>
                            {% for err in form.ownershipPercentage1.errors %}
                                <small class="text-danger ml-2">{{ err }}</small>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="mb-4 btn btn-primary btn-sm ripple-surface"
                    >
                      Add Shareholders
                    </button>
                  </div>
```

I want to know what I can do in this situation how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get tutorials for it and secondly whenever you input data from a form to models a new data like `dataname(1)` or `dataname(2)` is created for it so why do you need it to change field name itself where the data is stored!

simply write this in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class infoForm(models.Model):
    ownerName= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Owner Name 1')
    ownerRole= models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Owner Role 1')
    ownershipPercentage= models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Business Phone 1')
```

change the field names in all the templates and views you created and delete old migrations then run this in command line in `manage.py` directory:

```
python manage.py make migrations
```

Then this

```
python manage.py migrate
```

register your model in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import infoForm

admin.site.register(infoForm)
```

now try to enter data and see separate fields are itself created like `infoForm(1)`,`infoForm(2)`,...

Before you mess up get the best tutorials for it!